# How to use axios to make an https call?

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, proxy, axios

I am trying to use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) with a proxy server to make an https call:

```
const url = "https://walmart.com/ip/50676589"
var config = { proxy: { host: proxy.ip, port: proxy.port } }

axios.get(url, config)
.then(result => {})
.catch(error => {console.log(error)})
```

The proxy servers I am using are all in the United States, highly anonymous, with support for HTTP and HTTPS.

I am receiving this error:

> { Error: write EPROTO 140736580649920:error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:

In order to ensure that the problem is with axios and NOT the proxy, I tried this:

> curl -x 52.8.172.72:4444 -L 'https://www.walmart.com/ip/50676589'

This totally works just fine.

How do I configure axios to work with proxies and https URL's?

Answer (score 41):

Axios https proxy support is borked if using https proxies. Try passing the proxy through [httpsProxyAgent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent) using http.

```
const axios = require('axios'); 
const httpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const httpsAgent = new httpsProxyAgent('http://username:pass@myproxy:port');
// or const httpsAgent = new httpsProxyAgent({ host: 'myproxy', port: 9999 });

const config = {
  url: 'https://google.com',
  httpsAgent
}

axios.request(config).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Alternatively there is a fork of Axios that incorporates this: [axios-https-proxy-fix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-https-proxy-fix) but I'd recommend the first method to ensure latest Axios changes.

Comment: url should be outside of config, or you will get error "The url argument must be of type string".

Comment: @cyberspace what are you talking about? the request method wants a config object. Did you try this with get/post? because those do indeed need the url separate. Docs: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases

Comment: in my case had to add also proxy: false in the config

Comment: @Chris, yes, this is the point that it took me a while to get. We fix the issue with axios's proxy handling by not letting it do proxies at all, doing it all in the https agent (hpagent n my case) instead.

Answer (score 11):

Try this. That work for me.

First

```
npm install axios-https-proxy-fix
```

Then

```
import axios from 'axios-https-proxy-fix'; 

const proxy = {
  host: 'some_ip',
  port: some_port_number,
  auth: {
    username: 'some_login',
    password: 'some_pass'
  }
};

async someMethod() {
  const result = await axios.get('some_https_link', {proxy});
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can solve this problem looking [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072#issuecomment-567473812)

At this solution instead use the proxy interface, use the http(s)Agent.
For it the solution use the native node module `https-proxy-agent`.

```
var ProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var axios = require('axios');

const agent = ProxyAgent('http://username:pass@myproxy:port')

var config = {
  url: 'https://google.com',
  proxy: false,
  httpsAgent: agent
};
```

For it works the proxy property must be equal to false.

Comment: Confirm that this works great! However, if it is typescript, one can't directly assign `proxy: false` because it expects a var of "type" false. so I got it to work with:

```
    let setProxy: false;
    setProxy = false;

    let config = {
     ....
     proxy: setProxy,
     httpsAgent: agent
```

Answer (score 2):

The `https-proxy-agent` and `node-tunnel` solutions did work for me, but both of them doesn't support conditional proxying using NO_PROXY.

I found [global-agent](https://github.com/gajus/global-agent) as the best solution in my case as it modifies the core http and https objects and will be applied automatically to any library that makes use of them, including `axios`, `got`, `request`, etc.

The usage is very simple.

```sh
npm i global-agent
npm i -D @types/global-agent
```

Add `import 'global-agent/bootstrap';` to the entrypoint (`index.ts`) of the server.

Run with these env vars and make sure HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY are NOT in the env.

```sh
export GLOBAL_AGENT_NO_PROXY='*.foo.com,baz.com'
export GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

---

This is how I finally ended up using it.

```
import { bootstrap } from 'global-agent';

const proxy = process.env.EXTERNAL_PROXY;

if (proxy) {
  process.env.GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY = proxy;
  process.env.GLOBAL_AGENT_NO_PROXY = process.env.NO_PROXY;
  process.env.GLOBAL_AGENT_FORCE_GLOBAL_AGENT = 'false';
  bootstrap();
  logger.info(`External proxy ${proxy} set`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I hope this solution saves time for anyone facing an SSL issue with `Axios`.

- You can use an HTTP agent, I suggest using [hpagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hpagent)

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const { HttpProxyAgent, HttpsProxyAgent } = require("hpagent");

async function testProxy() {
  try {
    const proxy = "http://username:password@myproxy:port";
    // hpagent configuration
    let agentConfig = {
      proxy: proxy,
      // keepAlive: true,
      // keepAliveMsecs: 2000,
      // maxSockets: 256,
      // maxFreeSockets: 256,
    };
    axios.defaults.httpAgent = new HttpProxyAgent(agentConfig);
    axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(agentConfig);
    // Make a simple request to check for the IP address.
    let res = await axios.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

testProxy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly specify the port in the URL:

```
const url = "https://walmart.com:443/ip/50676589"
```

If you also need an HTTPS-over-HTTP tunnel, you'll find a solution in [this article](https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d).

Hope this helps,

Jan

Comment: Why a downvote? Axios had (has?) an issue where specifying the port number forced it to use the https agent rather than the http agent.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because axios is trying to proxy your request via https (it takes it from your url), there is this ticket tracking it: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/925

Answer (score 0):

I lost a day of work when I updated my dependencies last week (Feb. 2020) trying to figure out why services were stalling. `axios-https-proxy-fix` will cause Axios to hang indefinitely without timeout or throwing an error conflicting with other libraries in npm. Using node-tunnel (https://github.com/koichik/node-tunnel) to create an agent also works.

```
const tunnel = require('tunnel');
class ApiService {
  get proxyRequest() {
    const agent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
      proxy: {
        host: 'http://proxy.example.com',
        port: 22225,
        proxyAuth: `username:password`,
      },
    });
    return axios.create({
      agent,
    })
  }
}
```