# How to connect VPN using nodejs in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-16.04, vpn, privoxy

I have the code in my `nodejs` file which gives me the following information

```
host:"147.0.40.145"
method:"aes-256-cfb"
password:"9c359ad1ebeec200"
port:38473
```

I need to use above information and want to connect VPN through it. I have used below code to extract the above information.

```
const connectServer = (serverId) => {
  const token = store('access_token')
  httpOptions.Authorization = token.token_type+' '+token.access_token
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
   const response = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/servers/${serverId}/connect`, {'serverId':serverId},{headers: httpOptions})     
   console.log(response.data)
    resolve(response.data)
  })
}
```

So I need to know whether it is possible using `nodejs` to **connect or create** `VPN`?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Related (to connecting to VPNs in Node.js, not promises): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048832/node-js-programmatically-connect-to-a-vpn-or-route-http-requests-via-vpn

Comment: I have no idea. It would probably help if you added more detail. What kind of VPN, what errors you get, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry but I could not find  either code or any solution on the google for this. Even I do not know whether it is possible or not ***connect VPN using nodejs*** . The above code is just used to extract the information needed for connecting VPN. **:-(**

Comment: I believe it is explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240483/axios-https-request-over-proxy

Comment: @Eternal1 There is nothing in the link regarding the above question

Comment: which ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: @VikasYadav I am using **16.04**

Comment: You really need to provide more information and a better example. What type of VPN are attempting to connect to (OpenVPN, IPSEC, etc)? Why did you include the privoxy tag? What does it have to with this question? I fail to see how the code you posted is related to the question.

Answer (score 12):

Install this npm

`npm i node-openvpn --save`

```
const openvpnmanager = require('node-openvpn');

const opts = {
  host: '147.0.40.145',
  port: 38473,
  timeout: 1500, //timeout for connection - optional, will default to 1500ms if undefined
  logpath: 'log.txt' //optional write openvpn console output to file, can be relative path or absolute
};
const auth = {
  user: '{{add user name}}',
  pass: '9c359ad1ebeec200',
};
const openvpn = openvpnmanager.connect(opts)


 openvpn.on('connected', () => {
   console.log("Connected to VPN successfully...");
 });
```

For more info , please read this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-openvpn)

**Another option**
 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055112/8612835)