# Connect through VPN IP using node.js puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, puppeteer

So I have some experience using node.js puppeteer to open up chrome, click on buttons, and send keys to the webpage. Now, I was wondering whether it would be possible to do this through a VPN, the IP of which I could specify.

I would post a code snippet, but I really don’t know where to begin. Can anyone help me with this?

P.S. - if there’s a better node.js module for this, i’d be open to learning and using it. Said module just needs to allow me to connect through a VPN and then click buttons on a webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect VPN using nodejs in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449569/how-to-connect-vpn-using-nodejs-in-ubuntu)