# Node LDAP for VPN authentication connectivity library

Tags: node.js, ldap, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to the following connection using Node by plugging in my credentials so I can place some files through a firewall. I'm struggling to find the right library to use.

[image]

I tried using node-openvpn [(Answer from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449569/how-to-connect-vpn-using-nodejs-in-ubuntu) but feel it is the inappropriate library to use as I got the following error below:

```
const openvpnmanager = require('node-openvpn');

const opts = {
  host: '<IP_ADDRESS>',
  port: 10443,
  timeout: 1500, 
  logpath: './log.txt' 
};
const auth = {
  user: '<MY_USER_NAME>',
  pass: '<MY_PASSWORD>',
};

const openvpn = openvpnmanager.connect(opts)

openvpn.on('connected', () => {
  openvpnmanager.authorize(auth);
});

openvpn.on('error', error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Would give:

> Error: read ECONNRESET
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {   errno: 'ECONNRESET',   code: 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read'

I tried looking online for other libraries like [ldap-authentication](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldap-authentication) but it would need a url in the format of e.g. 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com' which I don't have

What library should I be using to accomplish this?