# How to use axios with a proxy server to make an https call?

Tags: javascript, axios

It's basically the [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240483/axios-https-request-over-proxy).

I'm using a browser. The following code is compiled by webpack.
I tried this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

var res = await axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
    proxy: {
        host: 'proxy-url',
        port: 80,
        auth: {username: 'my-user', password: 'my-password'}
    }
});
console.log(res.data); // gives my ip and not the proxy's one.
```

I also tried this with the same code, but it did not work:

```js
const axios = require('axios-https-proxy-fix');
```

Then, I tried with httpsAgent:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent')

var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent('http://my-user:my-pass@proxy-url:port');
var res = await axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
    httpsAgent: agent,
});
console.log(res.data); // gives my ip and not the proxy's one.
```

Is this a bug? Am I cursed or maybe do I have a problem reading the documentation?

Comment: Not too familiar with proxies in general let alone with axios, but at a glance should the port really be 80 for an https request?

Comment: What ip do you expect to get? Are you aware that propably you are browsing the internet with a single external ip provided by your ISP? What is the result if you remove the proxy thing from axios ?

Comment: @obermillerk it just works. I tested via an online proxy checker and my proxy is fine, even by going over HTTPS through port 80.

Comment: @leopal i'm expecting the IP to be the proxy IP and not my personal internet providers' IP. If I remove the proxy from axios, it's exactly the same. I asked a friend, he told me that axios was in trouble to handle proxies. But why did they document the proxy things if they do not work?

Comment: Have you considered using another solution? The Fetch API comes to mind, it’ll probably replace Axios and the likes in the future anyways.

Comment: @SumiStraessle no but now, yes. I'll check this today and even it does not answer the real question, i'll ask you to post your comment as an answer, if the fetch API works with proxies. I'll keep you updated

Comment: In that case this answer will be of interest I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524236/using-proxy-like-fiddler-with-fetch-api

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an <s>open</s> issue on [axios's github page](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072).

The issue is labeled as bug from 31 Mar and <s>is not resolved yet</s>.

So it seems you are not cursed, just a bug in axios.

You may add your details to that thread in order to dev team prioritize this issue.

In case you cannot wait for this issue to be resolved, you may consider using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like @Sumi Straessle proposed in the comments.

Comment: Indeed... I'll X-post what I said here, but I have just tested with node-fetch and in 5 minutes i've been able to do what in didn't succeed to do in 2 days with axios. i'll stick with node-fetch. Thank you for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 25):

if you want to use axios and work-around the issue then consider using https-proxy-agent for proxy agent as mentioned in [link](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/925#issuecomment-513028175)

```
    const HttpsProxyAgent = require("https-proxy-agent"),
      axios = require("axios");

const httpsAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent({host: "proxyhost", port: "proxyport", auth: "username:password"})

//use axios as you normally would, but specify httpsAgent in the config
axios = axios.create({httpsAgent});
```

Comment: Source for this fixed issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2072#issuecomment-592233032

Comment: Thought that was specifically for https proxies, but this seemed to fix https request on my http proxy!

Answer (score 3):

axios's `config.proxy` is Node.js only. I think it is meaningless in browsers.

You can check [lib/adapters/xhr.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/adapters/xhr.js) and will find nothing related to proxy there.

Comment: @user1974458 It does seem to work. In options: `proxy: { host: x.x.x.x, port: xx }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by doing so

```
const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(`http://proxy:port@username:password`);
axios({
   method: 'get',
   httpsAgent: agent,
   url: 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
}).then(response => console.log(response.data)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

My proxies are **https**, so when defining your **HttpsProxyAgent**, make sure to use **http** over https.

Answer (score -4):

If you are trying to access an HTTPS URL by an HTTP proxy, you need to create an HTTPS-HTTP tunnel.

I found the solution for this issue in this post: https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)