# React Native proxy for API requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to use a proxy for the API calls.
In `package.json` I set the property `"Proxy": "https://someapi.com"`, but this does not work. Is it possible to use a proxy in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible, but and you can set it in your API call. [follow this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62277342/12300188). you also can do this instruction in Axios interceptor. by doing this you only set it once.